# sending multiple inputs on ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i have a form where i get a collection of records, and after being present is shown like this:

```
  <input name="position" id="nameText" step-id="3" type="number" value="1" class="form-control stepinput">

<input name="position" id="nameText" step-id="4" type="number" value="2" class="form-control stepinput">

<input name="position" id="nameText" step-id="5" type="number" value="3" class="form-control stepinput">
```

The value is to later sort the records, and the "step_id" attribute is to send via ajax to update the specific record, but my data is not quite looking good. Wich is the best way to send my data to the controller to later being updated the records

My current code:

```
$('button.update-positions').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).closest(".steps-form");

            var map = {};
            $(".stepinput").each(function() {

                map[$(this).attr("step-id")] = $(this).val()

            });

        })
```

Comment: You should not use same ID for different elements.

Comment: You have 3 different inputs with the same id and name. That definitely needs to be fixed before anything

Comment: once you fix your inputs you can use jquery serialize http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: just serialize it as is, and then on the server receive the `position` values as an array. no need for step-id.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to read but if I understood correctly you:

- Have an 3 inputs of numbers
- Want the value entered being updated in the Database
- use *"step-id"* to identify which one to update

If so then replace step-id="" by **data-stepid=""** and the code for that would be:

```
$("button.update-positions").on("click",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest(".steps-form");

    var map = {};
    $(".stepinput").each(function(index,value) {
        map[$(this).data("stepid")] = value.value;
    });
    console.log(map); // Your map object
});
```

You can't have 2 elements with the same ID and you should use a data-attribute if you want to pass on information like so.